# Organizing my config variable for webapp2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, variables, python-2.7, webapp2

For simplicity I think I need to rewrite this to just one statement

```
config = {'webapp2_extras.jinja2': {'template_path': 'templates',
          'filters': {
          'timesince': filters.timesince,
          'datetimeformat': filters.datetimeformat},
          'environment_args': {'extensions': ['jinja2.ext.i18n']}}}

config['webapp2_extras.sessions'] = \
    {'secret_key': 'my-secret-key'}
```

Then I want to know where to put it if I use multiple files with multiple request handlers. Should I just put it in one file and import it to the others? Since the session code is secret, what are your recommendation for handling it via source control? To always change the secret before or after committing to source control?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add 'webapp2_extras.sessions' to your dict initializer:

```
config = {'webapp2_extras.jinja2': {'template_path': 'templates',
          'filters': {
          'timesince': filters.timesince,
          'datetimeformat': filters.datetimeformat},
          'environment_args': {'extensions': ['jinja2.ext.i18n']}},
          'webapp2_extras.sessions': {'secret_key': 'my-secret-key'}}
```

This would be clearer if the nesting were explicit, though:

```
config = {
  'webapp2_extras.jinja2': {
    'template_path': 'templates',
    'filters': {
      'timesince': filters.timesince,
      'datetimeformat': filters.datetimeformat
    },
    'environment_args': {'extensions': ['jinja2.ext.i18n']},
  },
  'webapp2_extras.sessions': {'secret_key': 'my-secret-key'}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend storing those in a datastore Entity for more flexibility and caching them in the instance memory at startup.

You could also consider having a `config.py` file excluded from the source control, if you want to get things done quickly.